# How do I find what extended character code is entered

Tags: universe, u2, unidata

I'm trying to see what's being stored in a record for the extended character è using ED editor in TCL, when I did the ^ arrow, it showed as ^!!!! invalid character.  I even tried to use UNISEQ on the character but it returing null.   Does anyone have any ideas?  I'm using Universe under Unix AIX.

```
02 ED TEST TESTEX
1 lines long.
----: t
Top.
0001: è
----: ^
Up-arrow display mode     = enabled
WARNING: Line has invalid internal characters, and may display incorrectly.
0001: ^!!!!
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try AE instead of ED. AE filename record-name. Then use the caret command "^" to show what values are there. Then you can use the R command (replace) to replace it. R/^123/^232/

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the record into a type 19 file (directory) and then open it outside of Universe with a hex editor.

Comment: Thanks again webthaumaturge, I found out the hex code for that was 'xE8', my question is how do I change these to '^232' or '&#232;' using ED or do you have any method you can recommend?  Thanks.